# jquery mobile navbar anchor does not fire after checkbox click/tap in <li>

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, click, navbar

I dynamically build listitems for an unordered list which seems to work fine as such:

```
var catList = "<ul id='lstEntry' data-role='listview'>";

if (selectedCategory.entries != null) {
    $.each(selectedCategory.entries, function (key, entry) {
        catList += "<li class='clsEntry' data-id='" + key + "'>";
        catList += "<input type='checkbox' id='isExcluded" + key + "'" + (entry.exclude ? ' checked ' : '') + "/>";
        catList += entry.title;
        catList += "<p class='ui-li-aside'><input type='number' min='0' style='width:20px;' id='weight" + key + "' value='" + entry.quantity + "'></p>"
        catList += "</li>";
    });
}

catList += "</ul>";
$("#divEntries").html(catList);
$("#lstEntry").listview();
//$("#lstCategory").listview("refresh");  //doesn't impact problem
```

Within the footer, I have a navbar with anchor tags:

```
<div data-role="navbar">    
  <ul>
       <li data-icon="plus"><a href="#" onclick="addNewEntry(); return false;" class="ui-btn-active">New Entry</a></li>
       <li data-icon="refresh"><a href="#" onclick="calculate(); return false;" class="ui-btn-active">Calculate</a></li>    
  </ul> 
</div>
```

The anchors work fine until I click/tap the checkbox in the listbox, or change the value in the input.  Once I do that, the first click/tap on any anchor in the navbar does not work, but the screen jumps a bit like an error occurred, but I don't have any errors logged (or I am missing it).  The 2nd, and subsequent, clicks/taps do work again.

I've experienced this in emulators and actual devices for android and wp8.

Does anybody have an idea what may be causing this?  I'd hate to have the user click twice if they first change something in the listitems.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was related to the data-tap-toggle property not being set on the div containing the data-role="footer'.  It should be set to false when there is possible interaction in the content area.

I found this through another post:
[Jquery Mobile Persistent Navbar - Flickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125271/jquery-mobile-persistent-navbar-flickers)